# Block Problem w w/o Replacement

Tags: probability

Assume that a bin has 40 green and 60 red blocks.  Four are selected at random. Let X be the number of green blocks in the sample. Construct the probability table for X assuming that sampling is:

a. with replacement

$$P(X=4)=\binom{4}{4}{2/5}^4{3/5}^{0}=0.0256$$
$$P(X=3)=\binom{4}{3}{2/5}^3{3/5}^{1}=0.1536$$
$$P(X=2)=\binom{4}{2}{2/5}^2{3/5}^{2}=0.3456$$
$$P(X=1)=\binom{4}{1}{2/5}^1{3/5}^{3}=0.3456$$
$$P(X=0)=\binom{4}{0}{2/5}^40{3/5}^{4}=0.1296$$

b. without replacement

$$P(X=j)=\frac{\binom{40}{j}\binom{60}{4-j}}{\binom{100}{4}}$$
$$P(X=4)=\frac{\binom{40}{4}\binom{60}{4-4}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{\binom{40}{4}\binom{60}{0}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{91,390}{3,921,225}=0.0233$$
$$P(X=3)=\frac{\binom{40}{3}\binom{60}{4-3}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{\binom{40}{3}\binom{60}{1}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{592,800}{3,921,225}=0.1512$$
$$P(X=2)=\frac{\binom{40}{2}\binom{60}{4-2}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{\binom{40}{2}\binom{60}{2}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{1,380,600}{3,921,225}=0.3521$$
$$P(X=1)=\frac{\binom{40}{1}\binom{60}{4-1}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{\binom{40}{1}\binom{60}{3}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{1,368,800}{3,921,225}=0.3491$$
$$P(X=0)=\frac{\binom{40}{0}\binom{60}{4-0}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{\binom{40}{0}\binom{60}{4}}{\binom{100}{4}}=\frac{487,635}{3,921,225}=0.1244$$

Can you please check my calculations?

Comment: In what you did, you should have on the left not $\Pr(X=j)$ but first $\Pr(X=4)$, then $\Pr(X=3)$, and so on. Your expressions look right. The computations are not, the probabilities should add to $1$.

Comment: ${40\choose1}\times{60\choose3} = 1368800$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is rather straightforward - since you replace the block every time you draw, the probability of drawing a green block is just 40% every time.  Use the binomial distribution.

For B, it looks like you've done the right thing - sampling without replacement requires the hypergeometric distribution.  But you should check your calculations - the 5 probabilities that you have do not sum to 1, and they should.  If you draw four times, you have a probability of 1 that you got somewhere between 0 and 4 green blocks. This looks like a homework question, so I'm not going to point out where the math error is; compare the fractions you get against the decimal values.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I got the calculation error and I'll try doing A now!

Answer (score 1):

Your working for B looks right. For A, since you replace the blocks every time, probability of a green block is $\frac{2}{5}$ and a red block is $\frac{3}{5}$ - use the binomial distribution.